# Customize WordPress default private visibility template page

Tags: wordpress, templates, private

got a question. Google did not help me :)
By default, when you set visibility page as private it shows a 404-not-found like a template for my page.

I need to customize WP private template in order to set a specific content of mine.

I don't want to create a custom template page and set something like

```
if (is_user_logged_in ()) {
    // f.e. Login/Signup with Facebook}
} else { 
    // show content
}
```

Just edit the default Wordpress template when I set a page as private.
Is there someone so kind to help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way which I recommend to add some meta box to your post type and display private and public content by applying filter on `the_content`

But still you are looking for some core hack then consider this example

```
function alter_private_query($posts, $query) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && !empty($query->is_singular) && isset($posts[0]->post_status) && $posts[0]->post_status == 'private') {
        $posts = get_posts(array(
                    'name'        => 'some-public-post-slug',
                    'post_type'   => 'post',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'numberposts' => 1
                ));
    }

    return $posts;
}
add_filter('posts_results', 'alter_private_query', 1, 2);
```

There is no filter when WordPress empty the `$query->posts` if user not logged in.
Still just above that you've a filter `posts_results`. Using this you can replace the `posts` variable by public post.

It is just to answer your conditional question, I won't recommend it at all. After all WordPress provide us ability to add many meta boxes. You can even display different content for each user without touching your template.

> NOTE: This can create SEO issue because you will have two same content
>   post with two different URL. Bots can not can not login into your
>   site.